# Google tag manager on Nuxt 2 - Google Analytics configuration tag not firing

Tags: nuxt.js, google-tag-manager

I'm currently working on a nuxt 2 application. We use the @nuxtjs/google-gtag & the @nuxtjs/gtm packages currently to configure 'Google Tag Manager' for our application.

We can see that some things work, but our marketing department says that the Google Analytics GA4 configuration tag should fire every page click/navigation.
But this doesn't seem to work.

Is this normal behaviour, Because nuxt2 obviously only loads the initial configuration once because of ssr. So should our marketing department measure things differently?

Or is our configuration off? Our current configuration looks like this:

```
gtm: {
    id: process.env.GOOGLE_TAG_MANAGER_ID || 'GTM-5TD2QD8',
    enabled: true,
    pageTracking: true,
  },
```

```
'google-gtag': {
    id: process.env.GOOGLE_TAG_ID,

    debug: true, // enable to track in dev mode
    disableAutoPageTrack: false, // disable if you don't want to track each page route with router.afterEach(...).
    additionalAccounts: [
      {
        id: process.env.GOOGLE_ANALYTICS_ID,
      }
    ]
  },
```

We've tried all kind of different combinations of settings for gtm and gtag but none of these changes actually work.

We've also tried creating a simple middleware to make a custom implementation but also did not really deliver what we where expecting.